# node-sass-middleware and css files located in node_modules

Tags: node.js, node-sass

I'm creating a web app that uses `node-sass-middleware` to render scss files. My problem is to render css files located in `node_modules` (`material-components-web` or `normalize.css`)

### app/server.js

```
app.use(require('node-sass-middleware')({
    src: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    indentedSyntax: false
}));
```

The css + scss files are located in /public/css/

### template/html

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/css-file.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/scss-file.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/material-components-web/material-components-web.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.css" />
</head>
```

### file tree

```
|-- public
|   |-- css
|     |-- css-file.css
|     |-- scss-file.scss
|-- node-modules
| |-- material-components-web
| | |-- dist
| |   |-- material-components.css
| | |-- material-components.scss
| |
| |-- normalize.css
    |-- normalize.css
```

### debug console

```
  source: [path-to-app]\public\css\css-file.scss
  dest: [path-to-app]\public\css\css-file.css
  read: [path-to-app]\public\css\css-file.css
  source: [path-to-app]\public\node_modules\normalize.css\normalize.scss
  dest: [path-to-app]\public\node_modules\normalize.css\normalize.css
  read: [path-to-app]\public\node_modules\normalize.css\normalize.css
  source: [path-to-app]\public\node_modules\material-components-web\material-components-web.scss
  dest: [path-to-app]\public\node_modules\material-components-web\material-components-web.css
  read: [path-to-app]\public\node_modules\material-components-web\material-components-web.css
  source: [path-to-app]\public\node_modules\material-components-web\dist\material-components-web.scss
  dest: [path-to-app]\node_modules\material-components-web\dist\material-components-web.css
  read: [path-to-app]\node_modules\material-components-web\dist\material-components-web.css
  source: [path-to-app]\public\css\scss-file.scss
  dest: [path-to-app]\public\css\scss-file.css
  read: [path-to-app]\public\css\scss-file.css
  render: [path-to-app]\public\css\scss-file.scss

GET /node_modules/material-components-web/material-components-web.css 304 7.978 ms - -
GET /css/css-file.css 200 16.435 ms - -
GET /css/scss-file.css 200 17.562 ms - -
GET /node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css 404 24.691 ms - 5378
GET /node_modules/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.css 404 28.336 ms - 5378
```

I tried different settings like includePath + scss files in public/css which import the css files located in node_modules. Nothing helped :/

Comment: Try using quesadilla (node scss express middleware) it solves a lot the configuration problems you maybe facing

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: @JamesSmith did you ever figure this out either?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have never found a better way than just copying files from one place to another. On reflection, trying to modify configuration to include SASS files from within directories other than a dedicated SASS or CSS directory does not seem like a very good idea. I'm sure there are fancy build tools that would do this, but personally I wouldn't go there.